# Python win32com excel remove interior color

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I want to delete the background color of an Excel cell using python and win32com.

If I ask the background color for an empty unformatted cell by `val = ws.Cells(r,c).Interior.Color` I get `16777215` which is white. If I set this value, I get a white filled cell but not a cell without background. Using `None` results in a black cell.

What is the right way to remove the background color of a cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-4142`, which is the corresponding value for `xlNone`:

```
xlNone = -4142
ws.Cells(r,c).Interior.Color = xlNone
```

Or instead of hard-coding, use `EnsureDispatch()` and then `client.constants.xlNone`:

```
from win32com import client
xl=client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

ws.Cells(r,c).Interior.Color = client.constants.xlNone
```